# If I turn this Python script into an executable, will others be able to execute it?

Tags: python, authentication, executable, pyodbc

I have a Python script that uses the pyodbc package to connect to a SQL Server database and runs some queries, saves it to an Excel spreadsheet and formats it for other coworkers to use.

It connects to the database/server using windows authentication, and not all employees have access to the database. If I turned my script into an executable, will it fail because the others who might try to execute it don't have access to the DB? If so, is there a way to link the application to MY windows authentication without hard-coding my username and password into it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible, you're going to want to create a dedicated user for this task. Do not include your credentials, even if compiled: your username / password can be extracted fairly trivially.

I'd recommend creating a user on SQL Server, with no access. Then GRANT that user SELECT privileges, only on the tables you need them to access:

```
GRANT SELECT ON table_name TO my_user
```

Then you can hard code the my_user / my_password into the script with a much smaller security risk. Good luck!

Comment: Fantastic, just what I was hoping for in an answer. Thank you. This should work!

Answer (score 1):

If your script is doing the authentication to the DB and that is coded into the script, then if the other have execute permission, they will be able to run it as designed.

Is the script running on a Unix/Linux host or a windows host?   Either way, you either need world executable OR group executable and have the users that need to run the script in the group.

On a unix/linux host, you can set the sticky bit, which would make it execute as the owner of the script even if a non-owner ran the script.